# bmWidthBytes unexpected size (monochromatic bitmap)

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc

I am seeing a slightly larger than expected value for the bmWidthByte parameter in my BITMAP structure. The MSDN website for the BITMAP structure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sf4cx2.aspx) shows what values are in the structure, along with some additional information for each parameter. The following is detail provided for bmWidthBytes:

> bmWidthBytes - Specifies the number of bytes in each raster line. This value must be an even number since the graphics device interface (GDI) assumes that the bit values of a bitmap form an array of integer (2-byte) values. In other words, bmWidthBytes * 8 must be the next multiple of 16 greater than or equal to the value obtained when the bmWidth member is multiplied by the bmBitsPixel member.

My structure has the the following values:
bmType = 0, bmWidth = 202, bmHeight = 105, bmWidthBytes = 28, bmPlanes = 1, and bmBitsPixel = 1

They way I would think I should calculate bmWidthBytes is by dividing my bmWidth by 16, rounding up to the nearest integer, and then multiplying by 16. At this point I would have the total number of bits, so dividing this by 8 should equal bmWidthBytes.

However for my values this gives me 26, which is two short of the 28 I am seeing. If anyone can point out anything I am missing, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think the documentation is incorrect - the width must be a multiple of 4 bytes, not a multiple of 2. It has been this way forever. The formula I use is `((bmWidth*bmBitsPixel+31)/32)*4`.

Comment: Can I ask how you're obtaining the bitmap? This might be a difference between device-dependent bitmaps and DIBs.

Comment: Mark: I am using CreateDIBSection() (so its its a DIB as opposed to a DDB). Also, do you know how long 'forever' is? I am working on a really old machine (win 2000) with a legacy program for WinCE.

Comment: Far before Win2000, I presume it's as long as DIBs have been around. I don't remember where it's documented though.